# How to find previous element in ordered dict which has a looked up value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an ordered dict with hours as keys, I want to find the last hour before the one given which has a given value as a value, if there is no such hour I want to return zero.

```
def get_previous_hour(od: OrderedDict, value: str, hour: int):
    pass
```

For instance for this input:

```
od=Ordereddict({1:"ala", 2:"a", 3:"a", 4: "dog",5:"a" })
hour=3
value="a"
```

it should return 2, beacuse it was the last time before 3 that "a" was a value.

For this input

```
od=Ordereddict({1:"ala", 2:"a", 3:"a", 4: "dog",5:"a" })
hour=5
value="a"
```

it should return 3.
And for this input:

```
od=Ordereddict({1:"ala", 2:"a", 3:"a", 4: "dog",5:"a" })
hour=5
value="dog"
```

it should return 4.
It is the first time I am using ordered dicts.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
hour = 5
value = "a"

prev_k = next(k for k, v in reversed(od.items()) if k < hour and v == value)
print(prev_k)
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you, and how do I return 0 if there is no such k?

Comment: Try, except StopIteration error is a good solution?

Comment: @RyszardEggink You can use `try: except:` or `prev_k = next((k for k, v in reversed(od.items()) if k < hour and v == value), None)` - this will return `None` if no key is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a deque like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, deque

od = OrderedDict({1:"ala", 2:"a", 3:"a", 4: "dog",5:"a" })
dq = deque([None, None], maxlen=2)
hour = 3
value = 'a'
for k, v in od.items():
    if k > hour:
        break
    if v == value:
        dq.append(k)
print(dq[0] or dq[1])
```

**Output:**

```
2
```